Error 91 - DataBodyRange.Copy ignore null
"DB" sheet contains 1 table with 3 Columns - Trade Date, ISIN, Trade ID. This is the output of a power query to pull data from the database (based on certain criteria) and display it here. 
"Current" sheet contains a range from Column A to E.
The macro has been setup to copy data from "DB" sheet and paste it on the next empty row of "Current" sheet.
Sometimes "DB" sheet contains no data. And it leads to error 91 when i run my macro.
tabledb. 
DataBodyRange.Copy --> this code is giving the error.
How to work around this?
Sub PullDBData()


Dim tabledb         As ListObject
Dim tableisin       As ListObject
Dim lr              As Long


Set tabledb = Sheets("DB").ListObjects("DB")
tabledb.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
tabledb.DataBodyRange.Copy
lr = Sheets("Current").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Current").Range("A" & lr).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
tabledb.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Set tableisin = Sheets("Current").ListObjects("ISIN_2")
tableisin.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False


End Sub


You can check with If Not tabledb.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then

hi, sorry, can you share where i can slot this in? i refer a lot of existing codes that are shared online without full understanding of what it actually does.

Trai placing If tabledb.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub just above tabledb.DataBodyRange.Copy code line...

You can check if DataBodyrange exists like this:
Sub PullDBData()


Dim tabledb         As ListObject
Dim tableisin       As ListObject
Dim lr              As Long


Set tabledb = Sheets("DB").ListObjects("DB")
tabledb.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

If Not tabledb.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then

    tabledb.DataBodyRange.Copy
    lr = Sheets("Current").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Current").Range("A" & lr).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
End If

tabledb.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Set tableisin = Sheets("Current").ListObjects("ISIN_2")
tableisin.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End Sub


